# Neo4j and parameterized queries

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I'm looking into using Neo4j for a project, but I'm a bit confused when it comes to best practices. I would normally assume that the official C# driver provides a method of parameterizing queries, but I can't see anything in the [official documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/).

There is what appears to be an unofficial library for C# located [on Github](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient) with a recent release only a few days old which supports parameterized queries. However, I also remember seeing a comment stating that it mostly supports version 2.x (although I can't find the page stating this). This library only supports http+https as connection methods, there is no support for Bolt. What effect will this have on performance?

What is the preferred driver/library for Neo4j 3.x using C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4jClient (The community driver) does in it's current state not support Bolt, there is a beta pre-release version (which you can get using Nuget by adding https://www.myget.org/F/cskardon/api/v3/index.json as a source to your Nuget) - I'm *reasonably* confident with it, but it does need testing.

It **Will** support Bolt though.

The official driver does support paramaterized queries you just have to code it yourself and when you call `session.Run` you pass it in as the second argument.

Something like:

```
var obj = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"Name", "Chris"}, {"Email", "a@a.com"} }

var paramsObj = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "userParam", obj } };

session.Run("CREATE (n:User {userParam})", paramsObj);
```

The official driver is supported by Neo4j, the community uses the official driver under the hood for bolt, wrapping up the OGM stuff, so the choice is yours from a Bolt point of view. If you need to use HTTP/HTTPS - you have to use Neo4jClient (which will work with 3.x DBs as well)

Comment: Thanks for the input. 
How will a similar parameterized query look when you want to find a node by a dynamic property? Eg. something similar to `MATCH (a) WHERE a.<propertyname> = <value> RETURN a`, where propertyname and value is to be determined at runtime?

Comment: Nevermind the last comment, I created a separate question for it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422028/neo4j-cypher-match-on-dynamic-property