# Neo4j/Cypher: Match on dynamic property

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

According to the developer manual section 3.2.4 on Parameters:

> Parameters cannot be used for the following constructs, as these form part of the >query structure that is compiled into a query plan:
>
> - property keys; so, MATCH (n) WHERE n.$param = 'something' is invalid ([source](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/))

Is there no way around this (c#, using the official driver)? I have a case where a node of a particular type can contain from a few up to hundreds of properties, and I want the users to be able to search for any of these without having to write all possible queries in advance. Ideally I'd like to be able to do something similar to

```
MATCH (a) WHERE ({prop} CONTAINS {val}) RETURN a
```

supplying a dictionary where `prop: "a.Description"` and `val: "Freeform item description"`

Is this at all possible, or is string concatenation (with related drawbacks) the only possibility here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cybersam's response is one way of getting the result, but as InverseFalcon said - you lose indexing performance - assuming you're planning on making the query a bit more detailed than just the example.

You don't need to write hundreds of queries (1 for each property), surely this is just a job for `string.Format`?  That way you get around the concat issue of string, and you can use indexing properly.

Something like:

```
const string QueryFormat = "MATCH (a) WHERE (a.{0} CONTAINS {{val}})";
```

which you'd use like:

```
string.Format(QueryFormat, "Description");
```

So...

```
session.Run(string.Format(QueryFormat, "Description"), /*params object here*/);
```

Presumably you've already provided a list of properties for a user to select from, so it makes sense just to pass that in with the parameters. `string.Format` doesn't have the issues that concat does so performance wise it'll be better in the long run as you can use the indexing on Neo4j when you get to it.

Comment: Many thanks, accepting this as the answer because of the indexing advantages.

Comment: Why is "string.Format(QueryFormat, "Description");"? How are the actual two parameters ({key} and {value}) passed into the query?

Comment: `QueryFormat` is a string in the `string.Format`structure, with a `{0}` placeholder. Which is the key, to add the value you'd want to pass in a parameters object with a 'val' key/value pair

Answer (score 4):

The syntax, `n['foo']`, can be used to reference `n.foo`.

So, this should work (I use the now-preferred `$foo` syntax instead of `{foo}` for parameters):

```
MATCH (a) WHERE a[$propName] CONTAINS $val
RETURN a;
```

Where `propName: "Description"` and `val: "Freeform item description"`

Comment: @bjelleklang This is the correct answer, though keep in mind that node lookups like this will be unable to utilize indexes for fast lookup (though you wouldn't be able to with this query anyway, since you're not using labels).

Comment: my propperty is a date. And I want to read year of the Date like `a[$propName].year` this gives error. I guess I have to use `apoc.cypher.run`

Comment: @canbax What is the error? And was created using the [date()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/#functions-date) temporal function?